# Multiple WCF Service References

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a WCF service that is being referenced in two projects that interact with each other. I have a class defined in my service that needs to be used in both projects but because of the different namespaces they are not recognized as the same class. For instance, in one class it would be project1.myservicereference.myclass and in another project2.myservicereference.myclass.

I don't have a lot of experience with WCF and wanted to know how others deal with this situation?

Comment: Put the class in its own separate assembly and have the 2 projects and the WCF service all reference it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to put your class in a common assembly and share that type between you server and clients.  Take a look at this: http://blog.walteralmeida.com/2010/08/wcf-tips-and-tricks-share-types-between-server-and-client.html

Answer (score 2):

Put the service reference in its own project and reference that project in all the other projects that need to access that service.